# GeoJSON - How to read a feature from an array?

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers-3, geojson

I have a map, on which I am drawing polygons that are taking their properties from a JSON file. 
According to feature values in the JSON file, each polygon is filled with a color.
An example of a feature from the JSON file is the following:

```js
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "767884",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [136.875, 35.17291667],
        [136.878125, 35.17291667],
        [136.878125, 35.17083333],
        [136.875, 35.17083333],
        [136.875, 35.17291667]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "parameterValue": 28
  }
},
```

Using the previous format, I could read the `parameterValue` and show it properly using the follwoing script

```
var colors = function(feature) {
var id = feature.get('parameterValue');
fill.setColor(
...
  id >= 20.00 && id <= 50.00 ? orange:
...
  )
return style;
};
```

However, I want to do the following

```js
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": "767884",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [136.875, 35.17291667],
        [136.878125, 35.17291667],
        [136.878125, 35.17083333],
        [136.875, 35.17083333],
        [136.875, 35.17291667]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "parameterValue0": [29, 28],
    "parameterValue1": [30, 29.5],
    "parameterValue2": [31, 21.9]
  }
},
```

and fill the polygons according the second element of the `parameterValueX`arrays. I have tried so by the following:

```
var colors = function(feature) {
var id = feature.get('parameterValue0');
fill.setColor(
...
  id[1] >= 20.00 && id <= 50.00 ? orange:
...
  )
return style;
};
```

but it kept filling the polygons with black, no matter what are the values.

Is this idea achievable? Could anybody please suggest me a way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just parse JSON to object?

Comment: @modernator Sorry, but I don't know about parsing JSON to object because I'm still beginner, but will search about it.

Comment: Simple, just " var data = JSON.parse(yourJSONResult);  data.type;  // 'feature' "

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem as following:

```js
var colors = function(feature) {
var id = feature.get('parameterValue0');
var id = id[1]
fill.setColor(
...
  id >= 20.00 && id <= 50.00 ? orange:
...
  )
return style;
};
```